# iPhone open YouTube video in YouTube App

Tags: iphone, youtube

I'm trying to open a video embedded in a page and a giant play button appears and the native video player opens and plays the video.

Instead I want to open the video in the YouTube app so I can see who uploaded the video and related videos.

Am I missing something?

An example would be:
http://sc2casts.com/cast17669-StarTale-yoe-vs-JINAIR-Best-of-5-2015-Proleague-Round-2

I'm on my phone. How can I simulate clicking the YouTube logo on my desktop.

Best

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to be dependent on how the website has embedded the video. In the example you give there is the option to tap the youtube icon in the bottom right which launches the youtube app. Some videos which play in the native video player unfortunately have no workaround to view in the youtube app.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In the chrome app under settings you can request a desktop version of the site. That gives you the YouTube button on the video which links to the app.